# Working with knockout templating

Tags: magento2

I have the below code, figuring out how knockout works... It seems I can't use any php inside . So how do I access the base URL or specific URLs? Sorry couldn't find anything in the documentation about working with this.

```
<li class="minicart-nav-item" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <!-- ko if: customer().firstname -->
                 <a class="customer-name" href="<?php echo $block->getUrl(''); ?>customer/account/logout">
                    Sign Out <span data-bind="text: customer().firstname"></span>
                </a>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko ifnot: customer().firstname -->
                <a class="customer-name" href="<?php echo $block->getUrl(''); ?>customer/account/login/">
                    Sign In
                </a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            </li>

            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                {
                    "*": {
                        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                            "components": {
                                "customer": {
                                    "component": "Magento_Customer/js/model/customer"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
```